# Failed Tor install on xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, tor

I installed Tor today, 02APR20.  Install placed a icon on panel and loaded the startup manager.  Neither Tor nor the manager will open and when I try, a program "Installing Tor For the First time starts, runs a bit and then hangs up on a box, "Verifying Signature".   I wait for over 5 minutes and nothing happens.
I have restarted Xubuntu 14.04 several times.  Now a box occasionally randomly appears "Installing Tor***" and runs a bit to "Verifying Signature" then hangs up.
I cannot find the file "tor-browser-en-us" in order to delete it.  I am told not to try to reinstall until it is completely removed. Please instruct.  I am  a Linux novice.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (and all flavors) is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: FYI:  Xubuntu 16.04 LTS is also EOL (*end-of-life*) as flavors only have 3 years of supported life. Use `ubuntu-support-status` to verify for your own install, but the oldest Xubuntu currently supported is 18.04 LTS (same as all flavors except Kylin for 16.04 which was given 5 years by Canonical)